# in linux, how best to have a c program look for files being made by another concurrent program

Tags: python, c, linux

**Background:**

This is on a raspberry pi and I'm a c/python/rpi noob...

I have a c program which looks for files in a particular directory using a while loop. When it finds one, it reads it, processes it and then moves it to a "processed" directory.

At the same time I have a python program making files which it writes for the c program to process.

The python program should have the "highest priority" because the c program will have periods when it can catch up on the workload in periods when the python program is not making any files.

I could rewrite the python program in c, but not vice versa.

**Questions**:

1. How can I keep the processing load of the c program light while it's looking for those files?
2. Can I use any kind of timer interrupt rather than a while loop?
3. Can I give any "priority" rating to either of the two processes?

Comment: inotify? ...................................................

Comment: nice/renice: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/nice-renice-command-examples/

Comment: @Martin James: ah, OK, I didn't know about inotify, very useful, thanks!

Comment: @7stud: nice/renice sounds like a good place to start. I have a lot to learn, thanks!

Comment: @JohnEllis, You're welcome.  You are jumping into the deep end of the pool!